# How does Android's account manager use the stored password to retrieve an auth token?

Tags: android, accountmanager

My question is about the Android Account Manager.  I'm not sure I understand the documentation below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

For the method: 
public AccountManagerFuture getAuthToken (Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback callback, Handler handler)

It says this:

> If a previously generated auth token is cached for this account and type, then it is returned. Otherwise, if a saved password is available, **it is sent to the server to generate a new auth token**. Otherwise, the user is prompted to enter a password.

I don't understand how the Account Manager would do this for my account type.  My assumption was that it would call a method defined in the AbstractAccountAuthenticator to do this, but I don't see any method that seems like it would re-submit a saved password.

1. To clarify, I was planning to save a refresh token as the 'password' for my account.  I was then planning to submit the refresh token in place of a stored password in order to get a new access token.
2. I tried searching in GrepCode but I'm not used to the way code is presented there, or the code isn't so clear, because I'm still not sure how the Account Manager plans to 'resubmit' the stored password and if I can override that behavior so that it instead just refreshes the access token.

Any help is appreciated.  I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override getAuthToken.  In that override you will perform the above workflow.  Saving the password is optional.  If you don't want to save the password then in getAuthToken you just validate the token that is saved already.  If the token is not valid you will prompt for the login or just refresh the token with some other mechanism as defined by your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, It just sounded like there was some kind of built in mechanism that I wasn't seeing.

Comment: No problem.  I appreciate if you find out differently to reply back so I can update my code as well.  Oh, and if you feel this is the proper answer, please mark it as such.